# Unable to Update Craft CMS & Plugins

Tags: craft3, updates, composer

When trying to update CraftCMS I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: An error occurred

Output: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for craftcms/cms 3.0.21 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.21].
- craftcms/cms 3.0.21 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
Problem 2
- craftcms/ckeditor 1.0.0-beta.2 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.21].
- craftcms/ckeditor 1.0.0-beta.2 requires craftcms/cms ^3.0.0-RC1 -> satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.21].
- craftcms/cms 3.0.21 requires enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 -> satisfiable by enshrined/svg-sanitize[0.9.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for craftcms/ckeditor 1.0.0-beta.2 -> satisfiable by craftcms/ckeditor[1.0.0-beta.2].

Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.
```

The problem is, the following is all OK:

- composer update comes back with "Nothing to Install"

Comment: @RobinSchambach So remove every package except the plugins I have installed at this moment?

Comment: Yes. You only need vlucas, craftcms + the plugins

Comment: But this above isn't the problem though? It seems to be throwing errors for CKeditor and CraftCMS?

Comment: If it's the same problem I had, from the issue linked to above, I removed the reference in the composer.json file

Comment: @Andrew Can you write an answer to the question on what your composer looked like after you removed the required includes?

Comment: Sure, AFAIK it's enshrined/svg-sanitize ~0.9.0 that causes the problem not CKeditor or CraftCMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original composer file that caused the error above looked like this:

```
{  "name": "craftcms/craft",
"description": "Craft CMS",
"keywords": [
"craft",
"cms",
"craftcms",
"project"
],
"license": "MIT",
"homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
"type": "project",
"support": {
"email": "support@craftcms.com",
"issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
"forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
"source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
"docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
"rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
},
"require": {
"craftcms/cms": "3.0.13.1",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "v2.4.0",
"craftcms/ckeditor": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"craftcms/redactor": "2.1.5",
"cebe/markdown": "1.1.2",
"composer/ca-bundle": "1.1.1",
"composer/composer": "1.6.3",
"composer/semver": "1.4.2",
"composer/spdx-licenses": "1.3.0",
"craftcms/oauth2-craftid": "1.0.0.1",
"craftcms/plugin-installer": "1.5.2",
"craftcms/server-check": "1.1.1",
"creocoder/yii2-nested-sets": "0.9.0",
"danielstjules/stringy": "3.1.0",
"doctrine/lexer": "v1.0.1",
"egulias/email-validator": "2.1.4",
"elvanto/litemoji": "1.3.1",
"enshrined/svg-sanitize": "0.8.2",
"ezyang/htmlpurifier": "v4.10.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3.3",
"guzzlehttp/promises": "v1.3.1",
"guzzlehttp/psr7": "1.4.2",
"justinrainbow/json-schema": "5.2.7",
"league/flysystem": "1.0.44",
"league/oauth2-client": "2.2.1",
"mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": "1.2.5",
"paragonie/random_compat": "v2.0.12",
"pixelandtonic/imagine": "v0.7.1.3",
"psr/http-message": "1.0.1",
"psr/log": "1.0.2",
"seld/cli-prompt": "1.0.3",
"seld/jsonlint": "1.7.1",
"seld/phar-utils": "1.0.1",
"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "v6.0.2",
"symfony/console": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/debug": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/filesystem": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/finder": "v3.3.6",
"symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "v1.8.0",
"symfony/process": "v3.3.6",
"twig/twig": "v2.4.8",
"yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.15.1",
"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "2.0.8",
"yiisoft/yii2-composer": "2.0.6",
"yiisoft/yii2-debug": "2.0.13",
"yiisoft/yii2-queue": "2.0.2",
"yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "2.1.1",
"zendframework/zend-escaper": "2.6.0",
"zendframework/zend-feed": "2.8.0",
"zendframework/zend-stdlib": "3.2.0",
"solspace/craft3-freeform": "2.2.1"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "modules\\": "modules/"
}
},
"config": {
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"platform": {
"php": "7.0"
}
},
"scripts": {
"post-root-package-install": [
"@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"@composer dump-autoload -o",
"@php craft setup/welcome"
]
}
}
```

So I removed "enshrined/svg-sanitize": "0.8.2", from the list in the compser file, and ran the update. The next error was given for Twig. So I deleted ""twig/twig": "v2.4.8" from the file, and ran the update again. This time it was successful, and the composer file now looks like this:

```
{
"name": "craftcms/craft",
"description": "Craft CMS",
"keywords": [
"craft",
"cms",
"craftcms",
"project"
],
"license": "MIT",
"homepage": "https://craftcms.com/",
"type": "project",
"support": {
"email": "support@craftcms.com",
"issues": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues",
"forum": "https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/",
"source": "https://github.com/craftcms/cms",
"docs": "https://craftcms.com/docs",
"rss": "https://craftcms.com/changelog.rss"
},
"require": {
"craftcms/cms": "3.0.20",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0",
"craftcms/redactor": "2.1.5"
},
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"modules\\": "modules/"
}
},
"config": {
"optimize-autoloader": true,
"platform": {
"php": "7.0"
}
},
"scripts": {
"post-root-package-install": [
"@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
],
"post-create-project-cmd": [
"@composer dump-autoload -o",
"@php craft setup/welcome"
]
}
}
```

So the update seems to remove a lot of the required references in the composer file. I tried doing this on a backup install first before doing the same on the live install.

Comment: Which is the same result as  Robin Schambach says above. Only Craft, vlucas/phpdotenv and the plugin, ie redactor, is needed in the composer file.

Comment: Andrew, does this delete all your plugins as well? Or do you add them back in and do composer update again?

Comment: No it doesn't delete the plugins. I imagine that the 'required' list in the json file is a list of required assets that supports the update. For some reason items get added to the list that aren't actually required. If in doubt I would try a backup version first. Hope that helps.

Comment: Doing the following removed all of my installed plugins also.